# precedence of python exception raised from within finally block

Tags: python, exception

I have some (python 3.12) code which really belongs in a finally block, but unfortunately that code can (in rare cases) raise an exception. Are exceptions raised in finally blocks guaranteed to take precedence over exceptions explicitly re-raised from exception blocks:

```
try:
    raise Exception('1')

except Exception as e:
    raise

finally:
    raise Exception('2')
```

This works as expected (this code effectively raises exception 2). It'd be nice to know if it's guaranteed to work this way, since I didn't see this case listed in the "complex cases" described in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: I did eventually find this in the reference under 8.4.4. finally clause, but it was hard to get a search engine to surface the answer - so I thought visibility on stack overflow would help others

Comment: You can post your own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exceptions raised in the `finally` clause are guaranteed to take precedence over exceptions re-raised in the `except` clause:

> If the finally clause raises another exception, the saved exception is
> set as the context of the new exception.

From the Python reference here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally-clause